# Error al calcular los números de Catalán | C++

Tags: c++

Muy buenas a todos. Desarrollando un algoritmo que imprimía los números de Catalán en un determinado rango me ha ocurrido a partir del valor 7 que el resultado de la operación decrecía considerablemente incluso a llegar a números negativos. Voy a adjuntar la parte del código que en verdad es importante por si existe algún error que he descartado o si puede mejorarse. Necesito que algoritmo funcione correctamente pero no encuentro cuál es el error.

¡Saludos!

```
void calcularNumeros(int extremo_1, int extremo_2){
    
    int operacion = 0, variable = 0, variable_2 = 0;
    
    // Ordeno los valores de menor a mayor
    
    if(extremo_1>extremo_2)
    {   
        intercambiar(extremo_1, extremo_2);
    }
    
    // Efectúo la operación en base a la fórmula
    
    for(int i=extremo_1; i<=extremo_2; i++)
    {
        variable = 2*i;
        variable_2 = i+1;
        
        operacion = (factorial(variable)) / (factorial(i) * factorial(variable_2));

        cout<<"\nEl numero "<<i<<" de Catalan es "<<operacion;
    }
}

int factorial(int &n){
    
    int calculo = 1;
    
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
        calculo = calculo * i;
    }
    
    return calculo;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para n=7 acabas calculando `(7*2)!= 14! = 87178291200`. Si pasamos a binario ese número vemos que ocupa 37 bits ... pues bien, resulta que el tipo `int` solo admite 32 bits. ¿Qué pasa con los 5 bits que nos faltan? se pierden.

Claro, cualquier operación que hagas a partir de esa te va a arrojar resultados incorrectos.

La solución pasa por usar tipos en coma flotante:

```
double factorial(int n){
    
    double calculo = 1;
    
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
        calculo *= i;
    }
    
    return calculo;
}
```

O bien tipos de 64 bits:

```
long long factorial(int n){
    
    long long calculo = 1;
    
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
        calculo *= i;
    }
    
    return calculo;
}
```

Por cierto, nota que no hace falta que `n` sea una referencia. Eso solo tendría sentido si fueses a modificar `n` dentro de la propia función o si fuese un objeto que no se pudiese copiar (por ser grande u otros motivos).

Para tu fortuna no hace falta cambiar más código, ya que haces toda la operación en la misma línea:

```
    operacion = (factorial(variable)) / (factorial(i) * factorial(variable_2));
```

Con lo que la conversión a números de 32 bits le afecta únicamente al resultado final, que es un número que va a entrar sin problemas en 32 bits.

En otro orden de cosas, por favor, reduce la vida de las variables a su mínima expresión:

```
void calcularNumeros(int extremo_1, int extremo_2){
    
    // Ordeno los valores de menor a mayor
    
    if(extremo_1>extremo_2)
    {   
        intercambiar(extremo_1, extremo_2);
    }
    
    // Efectúo la operación en base a la fórmula
    
    for(int i=extremo_1; i<=extremo_2; i++)
    {
        int variable = 2*i;
        int variable_2 = i+1;
        
        int operacion = (factorial(variable)) / (factorial(i) * factorial(variable_2));

        cout<<"\nEl numero "<<i<<" de Catalan es "<<operacion;
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias! Me ha servido a la perfección!

Answer (score 4):

**PROBLEMA**

No sé si el ejercicio está planteado para usar específicamente factoriales para su cálculo. Sin embargo, uno de los problemas al trabajar con valores factoriales es que pronto nos acabamos el tamaño en memoria máximo para almacenarlos.

Los [números de Catalan](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmeros_de_Catalan), son una secuencia de números naturales muy usados en combinatoria. Los mismos se pueden calcular mediante la siguiente fórmula (tomado de Wikipedia):

[image: Fórmula Números Catalan Combinatoria]

Sin embargo, los números de Catalan también cumplen la siguiente propiedad o relación de recurrencia:

[image: Relación de recurrencia de los números de Catalan]

La cual podemos re escribir de la siguiente forma como una fórmula recursiva:

[image: Fórmula recursiva de los números de Catalan]

```sh
Cn = 1; para n = 0;
Cn = (2(2n - 1) / (n + 1))*Cn-1; para n > 0
```

Los siguientes tres planteamientos a continuación, nos permiten calcular los primeros 34 valores de Catalan usando el tipo `unsigned long long int`. Para valores superiores, la representación queda fuera de rango, por lo cual tendríamos que usar librerías de enteros grandes (*Big Integer*).

**Solución Recursiva**

Podemos calcular el `n-ésimo` número de Catalan, usando esta forma recursiva que no implica el cálculo de factoriales y que en términos de costo computacional es mejor. Por otro lado, debido a las magnitudes representadas por valores de `n` superiores a 25, podemos usar un tipo entero `unsigned long long int` (C++ 11) que son valores en la escala del 0 al 18,446,744,073,709,551,615.

Por ejemplo:

```cpp
unsigned long long int catalan(unsigned long long int n)
{
  if (n == 0)
  {
    return 1;
  }
  else
  {
    return (((4 * n) - 2) * catalan(n - 1) / (n + 1));
  }
}
```

Notemos que la fórmula recursiva introduce el valor de `catalan(n - 1)`:

```
(4 * n) - 2) * catalan(n - 1)
```

como parte del cálculo del numerador, esto para evitar que el programa calcule y trunque por defecto el primer operando que se ve en la fórmula de recursión mostrada en la imagen:

```
((4 * n) - 2) / (n + 1)) * catalan(n - 1) // escribir así la fórmula produce resultados no esperados
```

La recursión usada puede afectar el rendimiento cuando el valor a calcular es demasiado alto. Este algoritmo tiene una [complejidad](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eficiencia_algor%C3%ADtmica) **O(n^2)** (cuadrática).

**Solución dinámica (iterativa)**

Podemos usar la técnica de [*memoización*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoizaci%C3%B3n) para mejorar la eficiencia del algoritmo anterior, pero aunque ganamos en términos de velocidad para obtener un valor nuevo basado en el que ha sido previamente calculado, siempre tendremos que realizar una primera ejecución para almacenar los valores de `1` a `n - 1` antes de obtener `n`.

La mejora implica crear algún tipo de estructura para almacenar los valores calculados y a partir de los mismos obtener el siguiente. Esto nos elimina el problema de la recursión y simplemente convierte el algoritmo en uno iterativo.

Por ejemplo, podemos hacer algo parecido a lo siguiente para calcular los primeros `n` números de Catalan:

```cpp
std::vector<unsigned long long int> iterativeCatalan(const std::vector<unsigned long long int> &lista)
{
  std::vector<unsigned long long int> valores;
  valores.push_back((unsigned long long int)1);
  for (int i = 1; i <= lista.size(); ++i)
  {
    unsigned long long int valor = (((4 * i) - 2) * valores[i - 1] / (i + 1));
    valores.push_back((unsigned long long int)valor);
  }
  return valores;
}
```

En el código anterior se calculan los números de Catalan basándose exclusivamente en el valor previamente almacenado en la lista (en la posición anterior). La lista se inicia con el primer elemento establecido a 1.

Esta solución también tiene complejidad **O(n^2)**, pero como dije en un principio podemos aprovechar que hemos almacenado los valores previos y podemos calcular los siguientes a partir de los ya almacenados. Además, no implica un proceso de recursión.

**Solución usando una fórmula combinatoria**

Tal vez en términos de eficiencia esta sea una opción más aconsejable, y es que si logramos obtener el valor del [coeficiente binomial](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatoria#Combinaciones_sin_repetici%C3%B3n) representado por `C(2n, n)` en la fórmula del número de Catalan `Cn`, entonces la complejidad de nuestro algoritmo será simplemente **O(n)**, que es bastante mejor que las anteriores.

Lo que debemos hacer es plantear una fórmula para calcular el valor de `C(2n, n)`: combinación sin repetición de `n` elementos, con `n < 2n` (claramente), elegidos entre los `2n`.

Una forma de hacerlo sería:

```cpp
// cálculo del coeficiente Binomial
unsigned long long int coeficienteBinomial(int n, int k)
{
  unsigned long long int resultado = 1;
  if (k > n - k)
  {
    k = n - k;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i)
  {
    resultado *= (n - i);
    resultado /= (i + 1);
  }
  return resultado;
}

// cálculo del número de catalan usando el coeficiente binomial
unsigned long long int numeroCatalan(int n)
{
  unsigned long long int coef = coeficienteBinomial(2 * n, n);
  return coef / (n + 1);
}
```

La fórmula usada en la función `coeficienteBinomial()` se deriva de la [definición algebraica](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coeficiente_binomial#Definici%C3%B3n_algebraica) del [Coeficiente Binomial](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coeficiente_binomial), en la cual se establece la siguiente:

> Si se tiene un conjunto con n elementos, de los cuales se van a escoger k, la elección (ordenada) puede hacerse de `n * (n-1) * (n-2) * ... * (n-k+1)` maneras,  ya que en el primer paso se tienen n opciones, en el segundo se tienen n-1, en el tercero n-2, y así sucesivamente, terminando en el paso k que tendrá n-k+1 opciones.

> Ahora, hay que dividir el producto anterior entre el número de selecciones «equivalentes».

La fórmula es la siguiente:

[image: Fórmula para calcular el coeficiente binomial]

¡¡Y con esto, estamos calculando el valor del coeficiente binomial `C(n,k)` de forma iterativa!!

Un programa que muestra las 3 formas planteadas podría verse así:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
unsigned long long int catalan(unsigned long long int n)
{
  if (n == 0)
  {
    return 1;
  }
  else
  {
    return (((4 * n) - 2) * catalan(n - 1) / (n + 1));
  }
}

std::vector<unsigned long long int> iterativeCatalan(const std::vector<unsigned long long int> &lista)
{
  std::vector<unsigned long long int> valores;
  valores.push_back((unsigned long long int)1);
  for (int i = 1; i <= lista.size(); ++i)
  {
    unsigned long long int valor = (((4 * i) - 2) * valores[i - 1] / (i + 1));
    valores.push_back((unsigned long long int)valor);
  }
  return valores;
}

unsigned long long int coeficienteBinomial(int n, int k)
{
  unsigned long long int resultado = 1;
  if (k > n - k)
  {
    k = n - k;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i)
  {
    resultado *= (n - i);
    resultado /= (i + 1);
  }
  return resultado;
}

unsigned long long int numeroCatalan(int n)
{
  unsigned long long int coef = coeficienteBinomial(2 * n, n);
  return coef / (n + 1);
}

int main()
{
  int num;
  cout << "Ingrese el número de Catalan que desee calcular:" << endl;
  cin >> num;
  if (num < 1)
  {
    cout << "El valor de Catalan para 0 es: " << 1 << endl;
    return 0;
  }
  // RECURSIVO
  unsigned long long int valor = catalan((unsigned long long int)num);
  cout << "El valor de Catalan calculado de forma recursiva para " << num << " es: " << valor << endl;

  // ITERATIVO
  std::vector<unsigned long long int> lista(num);
  std::vector<unsigned long long int> numeros = iterativeCatalan(lista);
  cout << "El valor de Catalan calculado de forma iterativa para " << num << " es: " << numeros[num] << endl;

  // BINOMIAL
  unsigned long long int vBinomial = numeroCatalan(num);
  cout << "El valor de Catalan calculado para " << num << " usando coeficiente binomial es: " << vBinomial << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Espero que esto aporte otra forma de resolver el problema.